# How to perform the operation in 1 blocking call?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How to perform this 2 operation become 1 operation? Actually i used in the background agent but the second operation cannot be execute and can not get the value. Any idea?

```
public void running()
{    
  ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoapClient test = new ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoapClient();

  test.ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference1.ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceCompletedEventArgs>(serviceClient);  

  test.ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceAsync();
}

public void serviceClient(object sender, ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceCompletedEventArgs e)
{

  answer = int.parse(e.Result.ToString());
}
```

Updated:
In background Agent:

```
        VibrateController testVibrateControl = VibrateController.Default;
        public int answer;


        protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
        {
            //TODO: Add code to perform your task in background
            running();

            ShellTile t = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

            StandardTileData d = new StandardTileData()
            {
                Title = "U have " + answer + " Invoice!!",
                BackTitle = "How Are You!!",
                //Count = 0,
                // BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("dog.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
                // BackgroundImage = new Uri("untitled.png", UriKind.Relative)
            };
            t.Update(d);

            testVibrateControl.Start(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            testVibrateControl.Stop();
            //ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?pp=cas", UriKind.Relative), d);
            NotifyComplete();
        }
```

In Main Page:

```
        private void CheckBox_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                PeriodicTask p = new PeriodicTask("jj");
                p.Description = "Don't push the red button";
                ScheduledActionService.Add(p);
                //ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(p.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                #if (DEBUG_AGENT)
                ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(p.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                #endif
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you able to give some context on why you're wanting it to be a blocking call? It may help people in their choice of possible solutions. (Also it gets past all the expected responses of it may lead to making the UI unresponsive if one isn't careful.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 99.9% of the cases, it is a bad idea to transform an async call in a blocking one, so I would be curious to hear why you'd need that.

If the second operation is never executed, there might be server-side or connection problems. Given that you are using a WCF service, use the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) to check whether the returned result is what you expect it to be.

From what I can tell, `NotifyComplete` is called before your callback is triggered, which is most likely the problem. While all other calls are stepped through, there is a potential race condition where the callback is just not fast enough to be triggered before the completion of agent execution is signaled to the OS.

What you could do is wrap the callback internally. Like this:

```
ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoapClient test = new ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoapClient();
test.ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceCompleted += (s,e) =>
{
   // Do some things here
   NotifyComplete();
};

test.ReadTotalOutstandingInvoiceAsync();
```

Moving on from there, why not have it return an `int` to begin with, so that you won't have to parse it out?

Comment: Thx @Den Delimarsky. If i put in the MainPage, the operation is run and i get the number of value but if i put in the background agent schedule, i would't get the value. How come will like that?

Comment: Edit your post to show how exactly you're using the code above in a background agent, as well as how you're scheduling the agent.

Comment: Thx @Den Delimarsky. I new in programmer and may i ask how to return the int value? is answer = e.result.ToString()?

Comment: Your value is already returned in e.Result. Just make sure that you're using the proper type in the service implementation itself, if you have access to it.